# how to detect documentready event of WebBrowser Control?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am somewhat stuck and trying to get the event firing when document is ready. do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
Public Class Form1
'Declaration
Public Event DocumentCompleted As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler

Private Sub Main(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Dim frm As New Form1
    'frm.Show()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://test.com")
    AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New  _
         WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete)
    Me.Text = WebBrowser1.ReadyState

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles Me.DocumentCompleted
    Me.Text = WebBrowser1.ReadyState
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the handler before you call the navigate method:

```
AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New  _
     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete)
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://test.com")
```